# Short cut to use one class for multiple input fields in Android Studio

Tags: java, arrays, android-studio

I have sign up, login, reset password layouts and codes all in one activity (or one page....hahahaha). They all have email editText e, e1 and e2. Now I created a method for each as shown below:

```
private boolean valEmail() {

    String mail = e.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();
    if (mail.isEmpty()) {
        e.setError("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mail).matches()){
        e.setError("Not a valid email"); return false;
    } else if (mail.length()>254) {e.setError("Email to long"); return false;}
    else if (mail.length()<5) {e.setError("Email too short"); return false;}
    else {
        e.setError(null);
        // e.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean valEmail1() {

    String mail = e1.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    if (mail.isEmpty()) {
        e.setError("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mail).matches()){
        e.setError("Not a valid email"); return false;
    } else if (mail.length()>254) {e.setError("Email to long"); return false;}
    else if (mail.length()<5) {e.setError("Email too short"); return false;}
    else {
        e.setError(null);
        // e.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
}

private boolean valEmail2() {

    String mail = e2.getEditText().getText().toString().trim();

    if (mail.isEmpty()) {
        e.setError("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mail).matches()){
        e.setError("Not a valid email"); return false;
    } else if (mail.length()>254) {e.setError("Email to long"); return false;}
    else if (mail.length()<5) {e.setError("Email too short"); return false;}
    else {
        e.setError(null);
        // e.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
}
```

If you observe, the method for each email (e, e1 and e2) are exactly the same. The issue is that the codes are too much and I am trying to make the codes as few and short as possible. I tried to create one method to handle this by using an Array but was not successful. Please how can I use one method to handle these? Any short cuts please?

Comment: Keep them seperate don't need to clutter whole thing in one activity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use one method for all email validation

```
private boolean checkEmailValidation(EditText e) { 
    String mail = e.getText().toString()
    if (mail.isEmpty()) {
        e.setError("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mail).matches()){
        e.setError("Not a valid email"); 
        return false;
    } else if (mail.length()>254) {
        e.setError("Email to long");
        return false;
    }else if (mail.length()<5) {
        e.setError("Email too short");
        return false;
    }else {
        e.setError(null);
        // e.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
 }
```

Now you can use `checkEmailValidation()` method for all email.

```
// you can check all email like following 
if(checkEmailValidation(e.getEditText()) && checkEmailValidation(e1.getEditText()) && checkEmailValidation(e2.getEditText())) {
    // do whatever you want here when all email is ok
}else{
  // ...
}
```

To use in multiple `activities` you can follow two way

1. Creat a `BaseActivity` and extend it in all `activity`.
2. Create a `class` and make a `static` method.

**BaseActivity Example**

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private boolean checkEmailValidation(EditText e) { 
    String mail = e.getText().toString()
    if (mail.isEmpty()) {
        e.setError("Field cannot be empty");
        return false;
    } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mail).matches()){
        e.setError("Not a valid email"); 
        return false;
    } else if (mail.length()>254) {
        e.setError("Email to long");
        return false;
    }else if (mail.length()<5) {
        e.setError("Email too short");
        return false;
    }else {
        e.setError(null);
        // e.setErrorEnabled(false);
        return true;
    }
  }
}
```

And extends `BaseActivity` in child `activities` like the  following

```
public class ChildActivity extends BaseActivity{
 // within this class you can use checkEmailValidation`
}
```

**Static Function Example**

```
public class YourClassName{
   private static boolean checkEmailValidation(EditText e) { 
      String mail = e.getText().toString()
      if (mail.isEmpty()) {
          e.setError("Field cannot be empty");
          return false;
      } else if (!Patterns.EMAIL_ADDRESS.matcher(mail).matches()){
          e.setError("Not a valid email"); 
          return false;
      } else if (mail.length()>254) {
          e.setError("Email to long");
          return false;
      }else if (mail.length()<5) {
          e.setError("Email too short");
          return false;
      }else {
          e.setError(null);
          // e.setErrorEnabled(false);
          return true;
      }
   }
}
```

Now you can call this `method` using `class name` like the following

```
public class YourActivity extends AppCompatActivity{
  @Override
  protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(getContentView());

    // you can use checkEmailValidation like 
    YourClassName.checkEmailValidation(...)

  }

}
```

Comment: Beautiful. This is exactly what I am looking for. Very short. The "Edit e" used for e, e1, e2 etc. Thanks very much. I will give it a try.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the String to boolean. ie from "private String checkEmailValidation" to "private boolean checkEmailValidation" and it worked like a charm. Thanks. if i am to create a class(in another page) and add the checkEmailValidation() codes, how can I use it or call it across multiple activity(multiple pages). i am new in android programming....